# React conditional rendering?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have a mapped component that displays tournaments/matches, and i'm struggling to get my head around a way to let users filter the tournaments by 'league', but still display them all if no 'league' is selected.

I have used recoil/atom to share the state of 'leagueFilter' to the component.
I tried using `if` statement to render my JSX, but running into multiple problems.

```
import { FunctionComponent, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { leagueState } from "../pages/trainer/[id]";
import { useRecoilState } from "recoil";
import PContainer from "./PContainer";


type Props = {
  tournament: Tournament;
};

const TournamentContainer: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ tournament }) => {
  const [leagueFilter] = useRecoilState(leagueState);

  if (tournament.league === leagueFilter) {
    return (
      <Box key={tournament.bout + tournament.league}>
        <Box w="fit-content" m="auto" textAlign="center">
          <Text fontSize="xl">{tournament.league}</Text>
          <Text>{tournament.bout}</Text>
        </Box>
        <Flex
          key={tournament.bout}
          wrap="wrap"
          w="auto"
          m="auto"
          justify="center"
        >
          {tournament.mon.map((mon, index) => (
            <>
              <PContainer key={mon.name + (index + 1)} {...mon} />
            </>
          ))}
        </Flex>
        <Text align="center">{`Score:
        
         ${tournament.wins} -  ${tournament.losses}`}</Text>
      </Box>
    );
  } else {
    return (same JSX as above);
  }
};
export default TournamentContainer;
```

This, sort of works, but only on the first render, and TS gives me the error:

`Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.ts(2322)`

Answer (score 2):

Don't do it in the child do it in the parent.

If leagueFilter has been set filter the tournaments with a `.fitler` if it hasn't just render them all.

Something like this:

```js
const Tournaments = ({tournmanets}) => {
     const [leagueFilter, setLeagueFilter] = useRecoilState(leagueState);
     let tournys = tournaments;
     if (leagueFilter != null) {
         tournys = tournmanets.filter( t => t.league == leagueFiler);
     return <div>{tournys.map(t => <TournamentContainer tournmanet={t}/>}</div>;
     
})
```

Comment: Thanks! this looks cleaner than my approach. I did quickly C&P your example and now for some reason, im getting error when i change the value of leagueFilter.

 `Error: Objects are not valid as a React child - If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: @Liiaam93 maybe a separate question? I don't think that error is from  my code. Somewhere you are returning an object instead of jsx `return <div> { {a: 1} } </div>1